# PHP XPath nested upper-case function does not work as expected

Tags: php, function, xpath, nested

While the first XPath will match a value element containing my sample text 'Macedonië', the second will not:

```
value[contains(text(), 'Macedoni')]
value[contains(upper-case(text()), 'MACEDONI')]

<value>Macedonië</value>
```

Is there a basic rule I am missing here? Does function nesting not work this way in XPath?

Gr.Viller

Comment: XPath 1.0 doesn't have an `upper-case()` function.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea PHP used 1.0 still (I'm trying XPath out for the first time). Is there any way I can achieve around the same effect I'm aiming for in 1.0? Seeing as I can still use the translate function, I might be able to use that to convert to uppercase.

Comment: Yeah, `translate()` is typically the way to go in XPath 1.0. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, XPath 1.0 doesn't have an `upper-case()` function.

A common trick in XPath 1.0 is to use the `translate()` function to convert between cases:

```
translate(text(), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
```

This isn't really ideal, since it doesn't handle accented characters or different string cultures (and that's particularly unfortunate given that the value you're looking for contains accented characters), but a lot of the time it's the only option.

Comment: I have used this principle and check against 'MACEDONI' (leaving out the ë, so there can't be any confusion). Thanks for the responses.